# Client not able to access live preview or offline site

Tags: live-preview, system-status

Is there any obvious reason why a client is not able to access live preview or an offline site? I've tested the login myself and it works OK. The client has tried using IE on a PC and Chrome and Safari on a Mac.

Comment: Did you enable the permission for your client? There are several permissions to create/edit entries and create/edit entries from other people and there is the permission for live-preview

Comment: Yes, all permissions are checked. I've tested the client login myself and all is OK. Could there be a problem with Javascript not being enabled on the clients PC, or a cookies issue?

Comment: I don't think so. If the client has Javascript issues the page would not work at all. Craft requires jQuery in order to run properly, so they would not be able to create a matrix or relations and such. Could you please explain what exactly happens? Do they see the button but nothing happens when they click on it. Is the button not there. Maybe you could ask them if there are any console errors?

Comment: +1 for checking for browser console errors.